# Visual Studio Devenv.exe high cpu Usage

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I am using VS 2013 ultimate, working on a project with Team Foundation Server. The problem is, every ten seconds, it hangs for up to 5 seconds, I am not compiling or anything, just writing code. `Devenv.exe` process jumps to more than 25% CPU and 670k of RAM. I have looked at the output from the JavaScript Language Service, and it constantly checks and says `Referenced file 'D:\tfs\xxx.aspx' not found`. Text search of the filename `xxx.aspx` in entire solution turns up nothing and I have the latest version. I think this is the reason of the spikes, does anyone know how I can turn off this feature in VS 2013?

EDIT: I have looked at other solutions, Browser Link is closed, I have the latest update

2. EDIT: I have found the solution, but I dont think it will really help anyone else. One of the guys referenced a hard drive path on top of a javascript page, and since the project is tens of thousands lines, cpu spiked as Visual Studio was searching it. Deleting the references helped in my case.

Comment: If the referenced file may be the issue, it's refer to the local file. Why did you think it's related to TFS server? You can disconnect from TFS server to check whether this abnormal phenomena still exist.

Comment: If I am not on TFS, I dont get the high CPU usage, however I seem to have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

To narrow down this issue:

1. Try to disconnect from TFS server. (In VS→ Team → Disconnect from
   Team Foundation Server) Check whether this abnormal phenomena still exist.
2. Use  `devenv/resetuserdata` command to clear user settings of VS,
   details refer to this blog: [VSTS Tip: devenv /resetuserdata](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ejarvi/2005/07/14/vsts-tip-devenv-resetuserdata/)
3. If you are using proxy in your machine, try to disable the proxy
   settings.
4. If there is anti-virus in the machine, also try to disable it.